# Sending a larger serialized object over the network causes glitchy behavior

Tags: c#, serialization, network-programming, arrays, packet-loss

I have been wrestling with serializing a object over the network for a small project I have been working on. The code I am using works almost flawlessly, sometimes the bytes don't load in correctly, but that is fixed by just reloading the UI. However, when communicating on the same system, but as soon as you go off onto a different system, the code only partially works. As soon as I try to send a size 30 string array across the network, the server stops reporting receiving packs, and oddly nothing throws an error consistently. There have been a couple errors that pop up now and again:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot block a call on this socket while an earlier asynchronous call is in progress.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ValidateBlockingMode()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer)
   at DMAssist.AsynchronousClient.Receive(Socket client) in C:\Users\crud4\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DMAssist\DMAssist\asyncsclient.cs:line 160
   at DMAssist.AsynchronousClient.StartClient(Object obj, Boolean expectresponse) in C:\Users\crud4\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DMAssist\DMAssist\asyncsclient.cs:line 119
```

This one is the main error that I keep getting in the console and I have no idea how to deal with it. I am not very experienced in network programming so I am left scratching my head as to where I have gone wrong.

My primary concern is that for some reason, the sever stops reporting receiving bytes when the client attempts to send over 330 bytes, and causes overall glitchy behavior. The server definitely shows receiving a connection, but simple immediately kills it for some reason. If anyone knows what is going on or how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance!

Client:

```
private netObject Receive(Socket client)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int iRx = client.Receive(buffer);

            object rawbytes = ByteArrayToObject(buffer);
            netObject recvobject = (netObject)rawbytes;

            receiveDone.Set();

            return recvobject;
        }

public netObject StartClient(Object obj, bool expectresponse)
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.
            try
            {
                // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
                // The name of the 
                // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 25599);

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.
                Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect to the remote endpoint.
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                // Send test data to the remote device.
                Send(client, ObjectToByteArray(obj));
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                Send(client, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<EOF>"));
                sendDone.WaitOne();


                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                if (expectresponse)
                {
                    netObject serverdata = Receive(client);
                    receiveDone.WaitOne();
                    return serverdata;
                }

                // Release the socket.
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

                return new netObject();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return new netObject();
            }
        }

private static void Send(Socket client, byte[] data)
        {

            byte[] byteData = data;

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }
```

Server:

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try {
                String content = String.Empty;

                // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket. 
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    if (bytesRead != 5)
                    {
                        Array.Copy(state.buffer, state.cleanbuffer, bytesRead);
                    }

                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                    // more data.
                    content = state.sb.ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Recieved " + bytesRead + " bytes");

                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        // All the data has been read from the 
                        // client. Display it on the console.


                        /*Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. Data : {1}",
                            content.Length, content);*/

                        object rawbytes = ByteArrayToObject(state.cleanbuffer);
                        netObject recvobject = (netObject)rawbytes;
                       }

                        // Echo the data back to the client.
                        Send(handler, ObjectToByteArray((object)recvobject));

                    }
                    else {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

 private void Send(Socket handler, byte[] data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = data;

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems to me that your Receive call on the socket (client) is a blocking call while your send is asynchronous. So while your send is still taking place (and I guess this is why it exhibits this behavior when your sent packet is larger) you are trying to block (in your receive) on the same socket that is still performing the asynchronous action. As is to be expected, you get an exception and possibly your send is aborted / socket is invalidated or whatever the documentation states.

Comment: So would I have to rewrite the client socket entirely to make it synchronous as well?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after a bit of fumbling around, I realized that my client was a mutant of async and sync sockets. So, I downgraded all of them to sync and it works fine now. The callbacks were sometimes glitching out and not moving onto the next level.